# boost symbols not found

Tags: boost, rosinstall, macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hit the following problem during install on Mac OSX 10.6:

$ rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"

...lots of output...

```
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linessrecord: 41.1 sec ] [ test_roswtf: 3.5 sec ]                              [ 2 Active 60/68 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
  -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
  -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
  -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  [rosbuild] Building package rosrecord
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/rhc/ros/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/rhc/ros/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/rhc/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /Users/rhc/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosrecord/build
  cd build && make -l2
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  Scanning dependencies of target rosplay
  [ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rosplay.dir/src/rosplay/rosplay.o
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rosplay.dir/src/rosplay/time_publisher.o
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/rosplay

  Undefined symbols:
    "boost::filesystem3::path::extension() const", referenced from:
        ros::record::Player::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Time, bool)in rosplay.o
    "boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()", referenced from:
        ros::record::Player::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Time, bool)in rosplay.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/rosplay] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosplay.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rosrecord written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/rhc/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110523-074829/rosrecord/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosrecord [FAIL] [ 41.13 seconds ]                                                                   
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rosrecord. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< test_roswtf [PASS] [ 6.72 seconds ]                                                                  
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Built 62 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] /Users/rhc/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110523-074829                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 467, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1200, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in <module>
    sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 547, in rosinstall_main
    subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s --rosdep-install%s" % (os.path.join(options.path, 'setup.sh'), ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 488, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/rhc/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I note that boost was successfully downloaded and installed by the ros install script, but wonder if perhaps the module isn't being found?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10030/boost-symbols-not-found/) by [ralph](https://answers.ros.org/users/580/ralph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an issue with the changeover from boost::filesystem v2 to v3; a wide variety of stuff breaks. Find the file that has `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` and add `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2` immediately beforehand.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-05-23**:
Vote me up? Accept the answer? :-D

**Comment by [ralph](https://answers.ros.org/users/580/ralph/) on 2011-05-23**:
Hooray! That got it! Found ~10 files that needed changing, but it ran clean afterwards. Thanks!!